# Excel crashes without errors when deleting a sheet via a macro

Tags: excel, button, crash

I have a macro that deletes a sheet and replaces it with another.  This new sheet is, infact, copied from another workbook.  The old sheet contains some buttons.  The macro creates the same buttons in the new sheet.

The macro itself is located in a module in the workbook and neither the old sheet nor the new one contain any macros.

One of these buttons is used to run the macro.  When the macro is run directly from VBA editor, it runs fine without errors.  But when the button on the old sheet is used to run the macro, excel crashes at the line where the old sheet is being deleted.

I understand that this may be because deleting the sheet somehow messes up the macro reference.  But I can't move the button to another sheet.  So how can I fix this issue?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you stepping thru the macro using the visual editor?  Probably best to determine EXACTLY which line of the macro is failing.

Comment: Best to post the code.